# Angular on a closed network

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, scripting

I copied this question over from SharePoint.StackExchange because I think it has to do with the library, and not SharePoint in particular.

I have built a few sample web pages with Angular and uploading them to my SharePoint 2013 library, referencing angular.min.js. Now I am working on a closed network with no access to the Internet, and my sample web pages are not working. I copied the latest version of angular.min.js (1.6.4) to this network and tried it in Site Assets as well as in the same library as my pages, but the Angular code does not work.

I have successfully used jquery samples with the jquery library in the same locations, and they work fine. Is there some other library besides angular.min.js that I need to upload? Do I need the non-minimized version of Angular?

UPDATE: Here is an example of what I am seeing. I am using the Angular samples from this tutorial here: http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/02/angularjs-tutorial

Exam 2 is a simple random number generator. When it runs correctly, on a site that is on the Internet, I see this in the browser (both Chrome and IE):

```
First Random Number : 5
Second Random Number : 6 
I'm feeling Disregarded
I'm feeling Inner Peace
```

From the console on Chrome, I see this (all four outputs are similar):

```
<h4 ng-controller="ctrl1" class="ng-scope ng-binding">First Random Number : 3</h4>
```

From the console on IE11, I see this:

```
<h4 ng-controller="ctrl1">First Random Number : {{randomNum1}}</h4>
```

Now, on my closed system, from IE11 I see this in the browser:

```
First Random Number : {{randomNum1}}
```

And from the DOM Explorer:

```
<h4 ng-controller="ctrl1">First Random Number : {{randomNum1}}</h4>
```

And from the debugger, I get this error:

```
Expected identifier in angular.min.js, Line: 80, Column: 346

'angular' is undefined (in my page)
```

While making making this update, I got this result from Firefox, which apparently works (I hadn't checked Firefox on Friday):

```
First Random Number : 5
```

And from the Firefox console:

```
<h4 class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-controller="ctrl1">First Random Number : 3</h4>
```

No errors in the debugger for Firefox.

Comment: what do you mean by not working? what does console say?

Comment: I get no response. The placeholders show {{field}} instead of data. It's as if the reference to Angular is not found, and I just have HTML on my page.

Comment: what does console say? There should be errors in the console showing the issues

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by console. The code is on an HTML page. The only output I know of is to the screen.

Comment: press f12 in your browser(or check how to open "development tools" in your browser) and open console tab, there should be some errors indicating what is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: In Document Mode, IE now works for Edge, 10, or 9. It breaks on 8 or below (and 5 was default).

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie - angular 1.3 and newer don't support ie 8 or below

Comment: I just figured out that's what it is. So, can I force document mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, my IE11 was setting document mode to 5. I added the following line in the head tag and it fixed the problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```